# Evolution of the downvote

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I know this is a recurring and sensitive issue.

I am not against the downvote the contrary, I sincerely believe that it is useful. But I think it should be constructive. We all have the right to error, among other things because English is not the native language of all and some times there are misunderstandings. This site is intended to find answers and also to progress. But sometimes, it's hard to understand the reason for the downvote.

This morning I had 2 downvotes for 2 answers was accepted one of which had this comment:

> "That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you"

In this case, the response was good and was perfect for the user who had asked the question.

I suggest implementing a system for downvotes, like for using flags. For example, using a list of justifications such as:

- Wrong answer
- Off topic
- Incomprehensible
- ...
- Other (please specify)

Besides, if there was a downvote for my question, I would delete it.

Comment: "Besides, if there has downvote for my question, I would delete it. ;)" - is that supposed to be a threat? Downvotes here can mean disagreement - which is something essential to have when having open discussion.

Comment: @Oded I'm pretty sure he meant that he's happy to let go of the idea if people resented it coming up again, but felt strongly enough about it to try.

Comment: @Oded: I'm sorry that you have taken as a threat. it was the humor and, if I was 10 downvotes without discussion, I would remove not pollute the site. And I just saw that my qestion was a duplication, I did not find.